# Does DIBAL-H reduce acid chlorides?

Tags: organic-chemistry

It's only really mentioned with esters, but acid chlorides are more reactive than esters, so following that logic is this a feasible reaction to convert acid chlorides into aldehydes?

Comment: Yes, according to this reduction chart from the Myers group at Harvard it gives the alcohol  https://hwpi.harvard.edu/files/myers/files/5-reduction.pdf    Other sources suggest the aldehyde is the product but this appears more authorative